# What can I do with whole wheat pastry dough?

Tags: dough, pastry, wheat

I used soft whole wheat flour to make pasta dough, following the recommendation [here](http://www.iitaly.org/magazine/dining-in-out/articles-reviews/article/durum-wheat-vs-soft-wheat-flour) that soft wheat flour is a traditional pasta ingredient. However, it's crumbling apart when I try to roll it thin enough. I'm looking for a plan B. Any idea what can I do with this whole wheat low-gluten dough, for dinner or dessert?

Comment: What kind of texture does it have?

Comment: Imagine a pasta dough, but a bit rougher and crumblier. For what it's worth, I put two tbsp of olive oil in the dough.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it into tart crust or biscuits and cookies. Of course, you need to know how much flour is in the dough and add the required other ingredients according to recipes.

Comment: Thanks, Backyard Chef! I was unsure about adding ingredients like butter once the dough has already been formed. Curious if people think that's doable. I ended up making ravioli, hoping they wouldn't fall apart. They didn't, but I had to make the sheets twice as thick as recommended, so the dish was weird.